# prompt validation if null not working inside funcion/while/try javascript

Tags: javascript

as said on title, validating the prompt if is null (inpname variable) inside the func/while/try wont work. output = {}
meanwhile the testing i did outside works fine.
check the code below please. what did i do wrong?

```js
//works
let test = prompt("testing","aasdasd");
if (test === null) {
  console.log("cancel");
}
else {
  console.log("ok");
}

let inpname;
//do not work
let func = () => {
  while (true) {
    try {
    inpname = prompt("name ", "name here");
    
    if (inpname.length > 10 || inpname.length <= 3) {
      throw "Your name must be at least 10 characters long, but not less than 4";
    }
    
    else if ( inpname != inpname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
      throw "A-Z characters accepted only!";
    }
    
    //problem here!
    else if (inpname === null) {
      throw "cant cancel";
    }
    
    else {
      console.log("success");
      break
     }
  }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      break
    }
  }
}
func();
```

Comment: The error being thrown is not the one you think it is.  You will see this if you use `console.error` in your catch handler instead of `console.log` .. but why exactly `err` is appearing like an empty object for `console.log` is a mystery

Comment: im new at JS, im programing at repl.it, console.log and console.error is doing the same there in this case, showing me the throws, except for the null validation, if i click cancel its null, so it should work like it worked on the test i did.

Comment: Yes it's null, but since you don't check if it's null before you call `.length` on it, its throwing "Cannot read property 'length' of null".  Just doesn't come up if you use `console.log` for some reason

Comment: maaaan wtf!!!! what a shame!! thank you very much how can i give you the "plus"?? i want to give you the answered question!!!

Answer (score 0):

The console outputting `{}` instead of the exception seems to be a bug in Stack-snippets.  You would get more correct output using `console.error`.

That being said, the issue you're seeing is in part caused because you're not checking that `impname` is null before you attempt to dereference it.

Changing the ordering of your error checking would solve the problem (Although stack-snippets is still not going to report exceptions as they happen, which is not the behavior you get in a browser)

```js
let func = () => {
    while(true) {
        var inpname = prompt("name ", "name here");
        
        try {
            if (inpname === null) {
                throw "cant cancel";
            }
            if (inpname.length > 10 || inpname.length <= 3) {
                throw "Your name must be at least 10 characters long, but not less than 4";
            }
            if (inpname != inpname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
                throw "A-Z characters accepted only!";
            }
            return inpname;            
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
}
func();
```

Note that you might want to avoid disallowing use of the "cancel" button.  If the user doesn't want to provide the requested info, simply exit the app with an appropriate message